# How to call python function/method in if else

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, if-statement, streamlit

I have been trying to call function to menu if condition is true. But not getting the desired result till now.

```
import streamlit as st 

class Gdrive:
    def gdrivee():
        # some code

    def local():
        # some code


options = {
    'gdrive': 'upload from google drive',
    'local': 'upload from computer'
}

selected_option = st.radio('Select page', options.values())

if selected_option == options['gdrive']:
    Gdrive.gdrivee()    # here i am trying to call one function


elif selected_option == options['local']:
    Gdrive.local()      # here trying to call function local
```

In the above code, I am trying to call function gdrivee() if chosen option is `upload from google drive` and call function local() if chosen option is `upload from computer` If you guys know how to make it work, please do share. would help alot:)

Comment: "*But not getting the desired result till now*" what does this mean? What issue are you facing? Is there any error? If so please add the traceback to the question.

Comment: You don't construct a class instance. Try *Gdrive().gdrivee()* Alternatively decorate *gdrivee()* with @staticmethod then your current code would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a more robust approach.

Construct a dictionary where the keys are the radio prompts and the associated values are the functions to be called.

Like this:

```
import streamlit as st
from pandas import Series

class Gdrive:
    @staticmethod
    def gdrivee():
        pass
    @staticmethod
    def local():
        pass

options = {'upload from google drive': Gdrive.gdrivee, 'upload from computer': Gdrive.local}

selection = st.radio('Select page', Series(options.keys()))

options[selection]()
```

Comment: when I ran the code as you suggested, on UI, it already pointed on the ```upload from google drive``` option and immediately start downloading from google drive and don't give the user any choice to select

Comment: @lungsang This code is designed to show how you could call the relevant functions based on a string (dictionary) lookup. It is not a streamlit tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Just check your condition the return value from **selected_option** might not be a string
So your condition is not getting satisfied.

```
selected_option = st.radio('Select page', options.values())
```

Try using type function to check the data type

```
type(selected_option)
```

The above type should be a string